# Select multiple columns in mysql using spring data

Tags: mysql, spring-data

I have following table

MyTABLE

> id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5

I am using spring data. I have following repository/DAO class

```
public interface MyTableDAO extends JpaRepository<MyTableEntity, Integer>
{
}
```

I want to fetch some columns say in one dao call I want to fetch col1 and col2, say in other dao call I want to fetch col1, col3, col5 and so on...

I want a return data in `Map<String, Object>`  where `String` is column_name and `Object` is value.

So I will say something like "select col1, col2 ...(here list can be any number of columns) from MyTable where id = 1" and it will give me map contains column name as key and value.

How I can achive that in spring data

Thank you :)

Comment: I think that is not possible. In spring data you can only query for objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a similar function in java couple of months back for doing some data post-processing.

Let me give a simplified version from the archives.

```
protected void printResultSetAsString(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    String firstLn = "";
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    boolean isFirstLn = true;
    String quote = "";
    if (ENCLOSEDQUOTES) {
        quote = LZConstants.ENCLOSEDCHAR;
    }
    logger.debug("Iterating result set and printing in the console ...");
    while (rs.next()) {
        Map<String, Object> columnsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            if (isFirstLn && includeFields) {
                firstLn = firstLn + quote + metaData.getColumnLabel(i)
                        + quote + LZConstants.FIELDDELIM;
            }
            columnsMap.put(metaData.getColumnLabel(i), rs.getObject(i));
        }

        if (isFirstLn && includeFields) {
            System.out.println(firstLn);
            isFirstLn = false;
        }
        String lineCSV = LZCollectionUtils.iterateMapValuesToLine(columnsMap, quote);
        System.out.println(lineCSV);
    }
}
```